# i get this error when run a program project "Server Error in '/' Application. Input string was not in a correct format. "

Tags: c#, asp.net

i get this error when run a program project  "Server Error in '/' Application.  Input string was not in a correct format.

Line 37:             if (Convert.ToInt16(GetPermission) == -1)

```
   Session["ModuleID"] = "1";
    usrid1 = Convert.ToInt16(Session[SessionHelper.CURRENTID].ToString());
    modid = Convert.ToInt16(Session["ModuleID"].ToString ());
    string GetPermission = DB.Exec_SQL("select Allow_add from UsercontrolMaster where Usrid='" + usrid1 + "' and ModuleID='" + modid + "'");
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt16(GetPermission) == -1)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
                //load Control

                if (Session[SessionHelper.OPERATION] == Constant.EDIT && Session[SessionHelper.RECORDID] == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/User Master/Default.aspx");
                }
            if (Session[SessionHelper.OPERATION] == Constant.EDIT && !IsPostBack)
            {

                Session[SessionHelper.DATA] = bndll._ReturnDatatableNew("select * from Usertable where Usrid ='" + _selectedRecordId + "'"); // Load Data from Data Table
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    filldata();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: line 7 : if (Convert.ToInt16(GetPermission) == -1) this is the line that throws the error

Comment: Clearly the value of `GetPermission` isn't a valid `Int16`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be many reasons for this problem. For every convert function converted strings may be null or not convertable strings. So when you call db data may return null. And after that when you converting GetPermission to int16 throwing an exception.

Check your values and make sure for your values are convertable.